# Merging, sorting and limit Map streams using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two maps `Map<String, Long>`. I want to merge both maps, sort in descending order, and get top 5. In case of duplicate keys in merge I need to sum the values. I have the following code that works:

```
Map<String, Long> topFive = (Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), 
                                           map2.entrySet().stream())
                                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                                             Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                             Long::sum)))
                                   .entrySet()
                                   .stream()
                                   .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                                   .limit(5)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                             Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                            (v1, v2) -> v1,
                                                            LinkedHashMap::new));
```

But I would like to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: If your code is already working, [codereview.se] is a better site to post the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean **better** in terms of **performance**, and you have large collections, and only need few top elements you can avoid sorting the entire map, given the `n*log(n)` complexity.

If you already have Guava, you can use [MinMaxPriorityQueue](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html) to store only the best *N* results. And then just sort this few constant *N* elements.

```
Comparator<Entry<String, Long>> comparator = Entry.comparingByValue(reverseOrder());

Map<String, Long> merged = Stream.of(map1, map2)
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                Long::sum));

MinMaxPriorityQueue<Entry<String, Long>> tops = MinMaxPriorityQueue.orderedBy(comparator)
        .maximumSize(5)
        .create(merged.entrySet());

Map<String, Long> sorted = tops.stream()
        .sorted(comparator)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (m1, m2) -> m1,
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

If you don't have/want to use Guava, you can simulate the `MinMaxPriorityQueue` by using a custom `TreeMap` (Also a class that receives the max size in constructor can be created, if you don't want to use an anonymous class [this is to show the functionality]).

```
Set<Entry<String, Long>> sorted = new TreeSet<Entry<String, Long>>(comparator) {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Entry<String, Long> entry) {
        if (size() < 5) { // 5 can be constructor arg in custom class
            return super.add(entry);
        } else if (comparator().compare(last(), entry) > 0) {
            remove(last());
            return super.add(entry);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

And add all the elements to the set with top.

```
sorted.addAll(merged);
```

You can also change the merge function, to use something similar to the merge mentioned by Federico.

```
Map<String, Long> merged = new HashMap<>(map1);
map2.forEach((k, v) -> merged.merge(k, v, Long::sum));
```

This tends to be faster that using streams, and after that, once you have the merged map, you can select the top N elements with `MinMaxPriorityQueue` or `TreeSet`, avoiding again the unnecessary need of sorting the entire collection.

Comment: In your first example you used flatMap. When I looked for an answer I came across some blog that said that flatMap is not good for large collections. Is that true? At the moment I have no exact knowledge of the size of my map but It can be around 1000 some times.

Comment: Stream are a bit slower, but for a collection of just 1000 elements the difference will probably be unnoticeable. You can use the map constructor and then the merge function, to generate the merged map and then use the `MinMaxPriorityQueue` or `TreeSet` to avoid the unnecessary sort of the entire collection. I'll mention that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to use an accumulator that keeps the top 5, rather than sorting the whole stream. Now you're doing an estimated n * log(n) comparisons instead of something between n and n * log(5).

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on making the code easier to read:

```
// Merge
Map<String, Long> merged = new HashMap<>(map1);
map2.forEach((k, v) -> merged.merge(k, v, Long::sum));

// Sort descending
List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> list = new ArrayList<>(merged.entrySet());
list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()));

// Select top entries
Map<String, Long> top5 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
list.subList(0, Math.min(5, list.size()))
    .forEach(e -> e.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

Also, by not using streams, this solution will surely have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another solution using a `Collector`. It uses a `TreeSet` as the intermediate accumulation type, converting the set to a map with the finisher.

```
private <K, V, E extends Map.Entry<K,V>> Collector<E, TreeSet<E>, Map<K,V>> 
        toMap(BinaryOperator<V> mergeFunction, Comparator<E> comparator, int limit) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mergeFunction);
    Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);

    Supplier<TreeSet<E>> supplier = () -> new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    BiConsumer<TreeSet<E>, E> accumulator = (set, entry) -> accumulate(set, entry, mergeFunction);
    BinaryOperator<TreeSet<E>> combiner = (destination, source) -> {
            source.forEach(e -> accumulator.accept(destination, e)); return destination; };
    Function<TreeSet<E>, Map<K,V>> finisher = s -> s.stream()
            .limit(limit)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(E::getKey, E::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new));

    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}

private <K, V, E extends Map.Entry<K,V>> void accumulate(
        TreeSet<E> set, E newEntry, BinaryOperator<V> mergeFunction) {
    Optional<E> entryFound = set.stream()
            .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getKey(), newEntry.getKey()))
            .findFirst();

    if (entryFound.isPresent()) {
        E existingEntry = entryFound.get();
        set.remove(existingEntry);
        existingEntry.setValue(mergeFunction.apply(existingEntry.getValue(), newEntry.getValue()));
        set.add(existingEntry);
    }
    else {
        set.add(newEntry);
    }
}
```

This is how you would use it, comparing the entries by value (in reverse) and using the `Long::sum` merge function for entry collisions.

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Long>> comparator = Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder());
Map<String, Long> topFive = Stream.of(map1, map2)
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(toMap(Long::sum, comparator, 5));
```